# $P(Y\leq X)$ where $Y = X^2$?

Tags: probability

Given that $X$ is continuous random variables and we know the probability density function and probability distribution of $X$.

We have a new random variable $Y = X^2$. We can easily found it's probability density function and distribution.

How I can use the above to calculate the probability $P(Y\leq X$)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq X)=\mathbb{P}(X^2\leq X)=\mathbb{P}(0\leq X\leq 1)$

Comment: but in the case P(X <= 2Y)?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X\leq 2Y)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq 2X^2)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq 0)+\mathbb{P}(X\geq 1/2)$

Comment: so there is no need to calculate the density and distribution of the y variable?

Comment: In these two cases, yes.

Comment: The idea is generally the same. If you have a quadratic that opens upwards, the set where its below zero lies between the two roots. If it opens downward, the set where its below zero is the complement of the set between the two roots. In the case $Y \leq X$, your quadratic is $f(x) = x^2 - x$ and you want to look at when $f(x) \leq 0$, which is between $0$ and $1$. In the case where $X+Y \leq 3/4$, you have $X^2+X - 3/4 \leq 0$, so you let $f(x) = x^2 + x -3/4$ which opens upwards and thus $P(X+Y \leq 3/4)$ is the probability of $X$ lying between the two roots of $f(x)$.